# How to log into localhost ords/apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm completely new to Ords and Apex so please bear with me :).  How do I log into localhost ords?  I've downloaded the latest 23 Apex on premise as well as the latest Ords  and set everything up.  I will not be using the cloud.  I did create a workspace from Windows and able to login on my windows machine but cannot on my linux server via terminal ($google-chrome).  My Linux is a virtual environment.  I can start Apex using Tomcat and can kickoff Ords by itself with ords config (java).  Below are my config props.  Any assistance you provide will be welcomed.  What is my workspace?  I have the username and password.

```
db.servicename=<serviceName>

standalone.context.path=/ords

db.hostname=<Ipaddress>

db.password=******

conf.use.wallet=true

security.requestValidationFunction=ords_util.authorize_plsql_gateway

standalone.static.context.path=/i

database.api.enabled=true

db.username=ORDS_PUBLIC_USER

standalone.http.port=8080

standalone.static.path=/home/oracle/ords/images/

restEnabledSql.active=true

resource.templates.enabled=false

plsql.gateway.mode=proxied

db.port=1521

feature.sdw=true

config.required=true

db.connectionType=basic

standalone.doc.root=/home/oracle/ords/bin/ordsconfig/global/doc_root
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear whether you're asking about connecting ORDS to the database or trying to use ORDS as an end-user from the command line:

If trying to login as a user, there is no command-line access to ORDS; you need to use a web browser and login through the APEX UI. You can interact with the APEX and ORDS PL/SQL API using SQLPlus or SQLcl as a client, but that is logging into the *database*, not thru ORDS.

If trying to connect ORDS to the back-end database, that should be covered in the installation guide, here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/22.1/ordig/index.html#Oracle%C2%AE-REST-Data-Services